# byte[] to gray scale BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

I start out with a 128 x 128 array of doubles and turn that into a 1D array of bytes with proportional values for each double.

I then take this array of bytes and turn it into a memory stream (`dataStream` below) and try and put that into a `BitmapImage` like so:

```
imgScan.Width = 128;
imgScan.Height = 128;
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.SourceRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height);
bi.StreamSource = dataStream;
imgScan.Source = bi;
```

Here `imgScan` is a `System.Windows.Controls.Image`

This doesn't produce the expected image (I just get a white square).

How should I be going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that in your code, the stream should contain a complete image file, not a raw block of data.   Here's making a Bitmap from a block of data (it's not greyscale, but you might get the idea):

```
const int bytesPerPixel = 4;
int stride = bytesPerPixel * pixelsPerLine;
UInt32[] pixelBytes = new uint[lineCount * pixelsPerLine];

for (int y = 0; y < lineCount; y++)
{
    int destinationLineStart = y * pixelsPerLine;
    int sourceLineStart = y * pixelsPerLine;
    for (int x = 0; x < pixelsPerLine; x++)
    {
        pixelBytes[x] = _rgbPixels[x].Pbgr32;
    }
}
var bmp = BitmapSource.Create(pixelsPerLine, lineCount, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null, pixelBytes, stride);
bmp.Freeze();
return bmp;
```

You've already done the bit in the nested loops (making the byte array), but I left it in so you can see what comes before the Create

Comment: Thanks, Will. One more question: what does stride mean? I can see you've set it to `bytesPerPixel * pixelsPerLine`, but I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: Stride is the number of bytes it takes to get from the start of one line to the start of the next in your data block.  In your case, it will be the width of your byte block, but in a case where, for example, you had three byte pixels (RGB888 perhaps), then the stride is often going to be a multiple of four bytes even if (3xnumber of pixels) is not a multiple of four itself.  It's so that lines always start on a nicely aligned memory address, and is really a hangover from the days when people cared a lot about perf details like this.